# Send data (text) between two computers using wifi connection C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I want to send data(text) between two computers (Notebook and SmartPhone) using wifi connection. I want to receive the data which are coming from SmatPhone in windows HyperTerminal.
Can anyone help!

Comment: Please add details of the specific issue you are having. If you do not understand how to do networked communications at all you should start at something simpler than doing smartphone to computer.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done, hyper terminal will connect to a port and wait information through these hardware. Over WiFi, the smartphone and the windows system should be establishing a sockets connection. Check out the Net namespace in the framework.